# Different integer resource values for phone and tablet?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-resource-qualifiers

As described here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Integer

I added a resource value for integer at /res/values/integers.xml

Now, I would like to add the same integers.xml for **tablet** devices? Like it is done for dimension resource files:

[image]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Use resource qualifiers on the `values` like you do with your dimens, for example `res/values/integers.xml`, `res/values-land/integers.xml` and so on. That is easier to see when you view your project as a file tree rather than the Android project view you have in your screenshot.

Comment: How would I solve this for tablets only? res/values-tablet/integers.xml ?

Comment: There's no such `tablet` qualifier. But you can e.g. override the value in `values-sw600dp` if that is tablet enough for you.